# How to correctly extract substring from a string in a Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of about 300 concepts and a pandas dataframe composed by two col: `Abstract`and `Title`. Some concepts from the list are in the Abstract as substring. I would like to extract from the Abstract the concepts from the list and use the extracted concepts as label for my record.

I am using the `.str.extract` function. I tried manually entering one of the concepts from the list

```py
dataset["Indexes"]= dataset["Abstract"].str.extract("(land reform)")
```

works as expected. However, since the list is about 300 concepts I would like use the list as pandas dataframe and use the dataframe as reference to extract the concept from the abstract.

I have defined the list as dataframe

```py
tofind = landvoc["English"]
```

then I have modified what I was using before as follows

```py
dataset["Indexes"]= dataset["Abstract"].str.extract(tofind)
```

but I got this error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

Any suggestions about how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.findall`:

```
concepts = fr"({'|'.join(tofind)})"
df['Indexes'] = df['Abstract'].str.findall(concepts).str.join(', ')
print(df)

# Output
              Abstract       Indexes
0  black and small cat  black, small
```

Setup:

```
tofind = ['small', 'black']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Abstract': ['black and small cat']})
```